# What are the different types of files generated by the GCC compiler for?

Tags: gcc

When running make on one of my C projects I'm playing around with, I notice that gcc produces different file types at stages. I'm curious as to what these are, as I'm not too familiar with gcc.

The extensions I noticed are:

- .o (I understand that these are compiled libraries)
- .o.lst
- .d
- .a

I hope this is not a silly question, but I'm just trying to understand these files, and what they're used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.o is object file ie machine dependent output code

> use gcc -c

.a is static library ... collection of several o files

> ar -r

.d file is the dependency file that contain the dependency

.lst -If you want to see the C code together with the assembly it was converted to, use a command l

> gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad [other GCC options] foo.c > foo.lst